# Try catch finally execution flow

Tags: try-catch

If an exception is thrown in catch block of try-catch, then will the finally block be called?

```
    try
{
//some thing which throws error
}
catch
{
//again some thing throws error
}
finally
{
//final clean up
}
```

Here, will finally be called?

Thanks,
Ashwani

Comment: Which language?, just in case...

Comment: Couldn't you just knock up a little test app in the language and find out..?

Answer (score 4):

In at least Java and C#, the `finally` block is always executed regardless how the try block exits.

If the answer were false, the `finally` construct would provide no advantage over simply including the code at the end of the try block.

Answer (score 1):

Even though there's an exception or not in the `try` block, `finally` block is bound to execute. That's the way `finally` was designed.

If there's an exception in the `try` block, then control will be transferred to the `catch` block to match the generated exception and will then switch over the control to the `finally` block.

But in this case, if there isn't any exception generated in the `try` block, the control won't be transferred to the `catch` block because there wasn't any exception to `catch`.
But as I said earlier, the `finally` block is again bound to execute.

> So, finally, the finally block will always be
>   executed

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. But what happens *after* the Finally block? To illustrate the full flow semantics, consider the following:

```
private int TryCatchFinallyFlow()
{
    int i, j = 0; // set j to non-zero

    try
    {
        i = 1 / j;
        goto lSkip; // comment out;

        return i; // comment out

      lSkip:;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        i = 2;

        throw; // comment out
    }
    finally
    {
        i = 3;
    }

    i = 4;

    return i;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;

    try
    {
        i = TryCatchFinallyFlow();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        i = -1;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
}
```

}

You can experiment with j being 0 or not zero, and with commenting out the three "comment out" lines. Step through in debug mode.

This will show you fully how the flows work.

Answer (score 0):

In every language I know: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

No if there is an exception in both the try and catch blocks as in your example above, control does not pass to the finally block. Illustration:

```
try
{
    //exception -> control goes to catch block.
}
catch
{
    //again exception ->  exits showing error
}
finally
{
    //control does not reach here
}
```

**NOTE:**
If however this above code is wrapped inside some function and there is proper exception handling i.e. try... catch block in the *calling* function, then finally block does get executed and control moves from catch above to the calling function's catch. Illustration:

```
try
{
    //exception -> goes to catch block.
}
catch
{
    //again exception ->  goes to finally block
}
finally
{
    //code here is executed -> goes to calling function's catch block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, finally block will be executed if there is an exception in catch block also.

This is the code of testing with debugging statements.

**Code**

```
public class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int i,j,ans;


        try{
            System.out.println("Debug statement 1");
            i = 9;
            ans = i / 0;
            System.out.println("Debug statement 2");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Debug statement 3");
            j=5;
            ans = j/0;
            System.out.println("Debug statement 4");
        }
        finally{
            System.out.println("Finally Executed");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Debug statement 1
Debug statement 3
Finally Executed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at Demo.main(Demo.java:15)
```